# How to use an iterator in this case?

Tags: java, iterator, arraylist

I have to iterate through an arraylist in this manner.

```
ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
li.add(20);
li.add(30);
li.add(40);
li.add(50);
li.add(70);

for (int i = 0; i < li.size() - 1; i++)
    System.out.println(li.get(i) + " " + li.get(i + 1));
```

#### Output:

```
20 30
30 40
40 50
50 70
```

How to do the same using an iterator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use two iterators. I tested this and it worked for me.

```
    Iterator<Integer> first = li.listIterator();

    // Will raise IndexOutOfBoundsException if list is empty.
    Iterator<Integer> second = li.listIterator(1);

    while (second.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(first.next() + " " + second.next());
    }
```

**Edit**: No need for inner `if`. Silly me.

Explanation: the `listIterator(index)` method returns an iterator that starts at the specified position in the list where as `listIterator()` returns an iterator that starts at position zero.

The `first` iterator therefore starts at `0` and the `second` starts at `1`. Then it is merely a question of printing the `next()` on both. This will work irrespective of whether the number of elements in the list is odd or even.

**Edit 2**

My logic fu is very weak today. Thanks [@barjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112053/barjak) for pointing out the case about the empty list and the unnecessary `first.hasNext()`.

Comment: 1) This code does'nt work if the list is empty. 2) `first.hasNext()` is useless, you can remove it. 3) An important thing to note is that the two calls to `next()` are necessary, even if the returned value is not used.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated:

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = li.iterator();
if (iter.hasNext()) {
    for (int y = iter.next(), x; iter.hasNext(); y = x) {
        x = iter.next();
        System.out.println(y + " " + x);
    }
}
```

or:

```
if (iter.hasNext()) {
    for (int x = iter.next(); iter.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + (x = iter.next()));
    }
}
```

Comment: without a hasNext() check, your .next() call may throw a NoSuchElementException if the list has an odd number of items. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29

Comment: This assumes always an even number of items in the iterator

Comment: There *is* a hasNext() check before each next() call. Both options work correctly with any number of entries (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,...). Well, if you don't believe me, try it out yourselves.

Comment: The second one is a little bit risky, as it relies on left to right evaluation order for string concatenation to work properly... I know that the Java spec guarantees that, but it's still a not recommended practice (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly Modified Sagar V's solution to make it work. One iterator is enough to achieve this.

```
Iterator iter = li.iterator();
        Integer int1 = null;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (int1 == null) {
                int1 = (Integer) iter.next();
            }

            System.out.print(int1 + " ");
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                Integer int2 = (Integer) iter.next();
                System.out.println(int2);
                int1 = int2;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, that can be appropriate depending on your needs.

#### Solution 1 : fixed-size view

The classical way to iterate on a subset of a list is to create a narrower view of the original list, and to iterate on this whole view. The `subList` method is used to create such a view.

```
List<Integer> l = // initialization code

int limitIndex = Math.max(l.size()-1, 0); // needed for empty list
for (int v : l.subList(0, limitIndex)) {
    // your code
}
```

Note that I used a 'foreach' loop, which is a convenient way to use iterators. This is strictly equivalent to this code :

```
Iterator<Integer> it = l.subList(0, limitIndex).iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    int v = it.next();
    // your code
}
```

Also, note that the `subList` method does not create a new list : it only creates a 'view' on the original list. The content of the original list is not copied, and all changes made to the original list are visible from the list created by `subList`.

#### Solution 2 : a custom Iterator/Iterable

If all you need is an iterator that always iterates from 0 to n-1, you can define a new `Iterable` tailored to that particular need.

```
public class NoLastIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private final List<T> backend;

    public NoLastIterable(List<T> backend) {
        this.backend = backend;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {

            private int nextIndex;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextIndex < backend.size() -1;
            }

            public T next() {
                return backend.get(nextIndex++);
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented");
            }

        };
    }
}
```

This class is used like this :

```
for (int v : new NoLastIterable<Integer>(l)) {
    // your code
}
```

#### Solution 3

You can even create your custom view of a `List`, just like `subList` does, but with more flexibility.

```
public class NoLastList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private final List<T> backend;

    public NoLastList(List<T> backend) {
        this.backend = backend;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        if (index >= size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return backend.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Math.max(0, backend.size()-1);
    }

}
```

Same usage as the other solutions :

```
for (int v : new NoLastList<Integer>(l)) {
    // your code
}
```

The benefits of this solution can be seen in the following situation :

1. the original list is created and initialized
2. the `NoLastList` instance is created (as a view of the original List)
3. some elements are added to the original list

In this situation, iterating over `NoLastList` will take into account the elements that were added lately. `NoLastList` always represents a view of the elements from 0 to n-1, even if n (the size) changes.